# MongoDB aggregation exceeded 16mb why?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation

I'm using pymongo 3.5. The following query throws an exception telling me that the BSON Document exceeds the 16mb limit. 
But how is it possible? 
I've used the "$out" option to write the results in a collection instead of returning a value.

```
pipeline = [
        {"$match": match_dict},
        {"$unwind": "$fields"},
        {"$match": {
                field_types[field_type]:field
        }},
        { "$group": {
                "_id": "$fields.value",
                "count" : {"$sum" : 1},
                "unique_ids" : {"$addToSet" : {"doc":"$_id","items":"$items"}},
        }},
        {"$unwind": "$unique_ids"},
        { "$group": {
                "_id": {"value":"$_id","count":"$count"},
                "items_sum" : {"$sum" : "$unique_ids.items"}
        }},
        { "$project" : {
            "_id": {"value":"$_id.value"},
            "count" : "$_id.count",
            "items_sum" : "$items_sum"
        }},
        {"$out": collection_name}
]
db.records.aggregate(pipeline,allowDiskUse=True)
```

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/) says that during the pipeline processing, the documents may exceed this size.

An example of the expected result is this:

```
[{"count": 79293, "_id": {"value": "06101"}, "items_sum": 111700},
{"count": 47352, "_id": {"value": "06120"},...]
```

Data structure:

```
{
"_id": <the_doc_id>
"items": 30,
"fields": [
    {
        "marc_field_subfield": "008",
        "value": "150504s2010    gr abe  r     000 0 gre|c"
    },
    {
        "marc_field_subfield": "020a",
        "value": "9789604751235"
    },
    {
        "marc_field_subfield": "020q"
        "value": "(\u03c7\u03b1\u03c1\u03c4\u03cc\u03b4.)"
    },
    {
        "marc_field_subfield": "040a"
        "value": "GR-KeIUL"
    },
    {
        "marc_field_subfield": "040a"
        "value": "EL"
    }
]
}
```

The `field_types[field_type]:field` matches a specific `marc_field_subfield` which can exist more than one times in the fields array (e.g. "040a")

Comment: Please the document result of the aggregate pipeline

Comment: I've updated the question with the expected result!

Comment: You could attempt to shorten your field names (as in "value"-->"v", "count"-->"c", "items_sum"-->"s") and see if that works. Or limit the number of output items (start with 1 and then steadily increase) and see what sort (size) of results you really produce.

Comment: unfortunately I tried shortening the names with no success. The number of output "items" is not a problem, it breaks in the first "fields.value". It's not normal, the documentation says clearly that the size does not count in the pipeline, only in the end result and the end result is small!

Comment: The problem is the first `$group` , where the `$addToSet` causes a grouped document ( and it need only be one ) to exceed the limit, simply because the resulting array is too big. You avoid this by instead refactoring to include the same keys being included in `$addToSet` within the grouping `_id `instead. It's not the out or the cursor because those are different errors, It's not clear in your question what the actual structure of original data is because you have not included it. This makes it difficult to determine the best way to get your "count" total. Or indeed a better overall approach

Comment: @NeilLunn I've added the data structure